# Reliability of automated compilation and deployment

Tags: continuous-integration, web-deployment

Lets say I build my code locally and then deploy the binaries. In this instance I know that the binaries on the server were compiled from the correct source.

So lets say instead I build my code locally and it works so I push the code to source control. A CI server detects the change, checks out the source and recompiles successfully and pushes the binaries live.

So the beginning and end of the two processes are the same. But the second has more room for error. For example, my commit to the source control might have errors. I might fail to commit all the changed files but the source might still compile.

How can I be sure that the source code in source control is the same as I have locally?

Comment: When you say "then deploy the binaries", you mean that you are deploying the binaries to a dev, test or production server?

Comment: I meant production. But I think regardless there's the potential for the error I'm describing.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is: If you use a CI server you should never deploy anything to test, preview or production server manually.

Normally, I have a build configuration, on CI server, with many steps, like:

1. Compilation
2. [Static code analysis (like FxCop, PMD, etc).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis)
3. [Unit tests (nunit, junit, etc).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks)
4. Deploy to test server. Many web techs have easy ways to do this step, like the Web Deploy for ASP .NET sites. This site version will be used as a target for the next 2 steps.
5. [Functional tests (selenium, sikuli, etc).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools)
6. Performance tests. For web sites and web apis we use [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/).
7. Package the final artifacts. Maybe will need to generate a installer, maybe just .zip file with deploy files.

With all steps (you should have a good code coverage in step 3 and good user case tests on step 4), you can have more confidence to deploy the final files generate from step 7 to the production server.

Comment: This doesn't address the question though. When you do step one, how do you know that source control has the correct source files? An error may have occurred during the commit.